# Need to pivot pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I downloaded a csv from the world bank website that has stats for Australia going back to 1960(https://data.worldbank.org/country/australia) .  I have read the csv in to a pandas dataframe but after removing unnecessary rows and columns it has the years as columns and the stat fields as rows:

```
# Load the data
df = pd.read_csv('Aus_stats.csv', header=2)
rate = pd.read_csv('AUDUSD historical rate from 1960.csv')

# Data Munging
# years = range(1960, 2022, 1)
df.drop(df.columns[[0,1,2]], axis = 1, inplace = True)
df
```

[Output from df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BUxj.png)

When I try and pivot the table to have the years as the index (as I am trying to get to) then I end up with the following:

```
df = df.pivot(columns = 'Indicator Code', index = ['1960'])
df
```

[Output after pivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKADf.png)

Ideally I want to see each stat indicator as the column headers and have the years (1960-2022) as the index for the rows

Comment: I don't know but the code run exactly. Can you share your desired output?

Comment: Provide your dataframe as code using `df.head().to_dict()` and not as a screenshot.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is the df.head().to_dict() output: {('1960', 'AG.AGR.TRAC.NO'): {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 ('1960', 'AG.CON.FERT.PT.ZS'): {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 ('1960', 'AG.CON.FERT.ZS'): {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 ('1960', 'AG.LND.AGRI.K2'): {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 ('1960', 'AG.LND.AGRI.ZS'): {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 ('1960', 'AG.LND.ARBL.HA'): {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
This is the first 5 lines of the 94592 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.set_index("Indicator Code").transpose()
```

Comment: Thanks, transpose worked, just need to clean up the columns and rows now